# What is the difference between 'Objects -> Threads' and 'Process -> Thread Count' in Performance Monitor?

Tags: windows, performance-monitor

Two counters in performance monitor are "Threads" under "Objects" and "Thread Count" under "Process".

On machines I've looked at, there is a large difference between the values for the two counters, with Objects > Threads much larger. What does the difference between the two values indicate?

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with *Process* → *Thread Count* for the *_Total* instance. This counter just goes through every process, gets its thread count, and totals that up. Doing that gives the same number as this PowerShell command:

```
(gwmi -Query "select threadcount from win32_process" | Select-Object -Property ThreadCount | Measure-Object ThreadCount -Sum).Sum
```

That total, on my machine, is about 400 less than the *Objects* → *Threads* counter.

One hypothesis for the discrepancy is this: In user-mode, every thread is associated with a process. Kernel-mode drivers, however, can create [device-dedicated threads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff543102(v=VS.85).aspx), which don't ever execute user-mode code and therefore, it would appear that they aren't picked up by an inspection of user-mode processes. However, it looks like the System process takes responsibility for drivers' threads, so this explanation is probably not right.

A more likely explanation is that while the above command counts all running threads, there are still thread objects that (though terminated) have not been cleaned up. Since [some thread bookkeeping is kept around until all programs let go of their knowledge about it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686746(v=vs.85).aspx), living processes holding handles to dead threads might cause the difference.

Somewhat relevant: [Internals of Windows Thread](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/662735/Internals-of-Windows-Thread).